# Did i install this Google analytics code correctly?

Tags: google, javascript, analytics

All,

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I installed the code at the bottom of each page before the body tag but after 3 or 4 days the GA webpage is giving me no response ( just the yellow triangle)

I previously asked this question and much to my embarrassment i uploaded the incorrect version of the website with no GA code at all.

Now I have and its still not responding

What am I doing wrong?

www.barbrow.com\barbrowtree\

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra slash in the close script tag. Use `</script>` rather than `<//script>`.

And you may want to run your pages through an [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to make sure there is nothing else wrong with the code.

Comment: thanks ill try that out If its write ill Check you till then +1

Answer (score 2):

The code you've used isn't the same as the code google says to use [here](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55488). You've got part of the document.write line missing from your code. You also seem to have two slashes at the end of a lot of your tags, and also preceding some of your quotation marks (from attempts to escape them in your code?).

Answer (score 2):

I found the following article on the Google Help, which may answer your question.

[What should I know about using Analytics with framed sites?](http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55598)

> **1. Where should I place my tracking
>       code?**
>
> We recommend that a site which uses
>   frames include the tracking code in
>   the  section of the frameset
>   page, as well as directly before the
>    tag of each child frame that
>   you want to track. (The tracking code
>   goes into the head section of the
>   frameset page, as these documents
>   don't contain a body section.) If you
>   place your tracking code within a
>    tag thinking that it's
>   equivalent to the body, the code will
>   not run and no data will be recorded.

Answer (score 0):

copy and paste code that has been provided to you by google and before last  enter paste that code there... and you done